# estimating gaussian like integral

Tags: calculus, probability

How do we estimate the following kind of integrals -
$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^r} dx $ For r > 1.
I basically need this to find normalization constants for probability measures with densities proportional to the integrand(had to write the last line to meet quality standards).

Comment: See my answer to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639648) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^r}\, \mathrm{d}x = \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right) \quad , r>1$$

Where $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

This is 3.326 in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik (1979/1980), using $\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right) = \frac{1}{r}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$.  Turns out the above is valid for $\Re\ r > 0$.

Comment: Don't you think that this is valid for any $r>0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici:  It is valid for any $r$ with positive real part, as I noted in the last line.