# Integral of factorial function

Tags: integration, factorial

$$
\mbox{What can we say about the integral}\quad
\int_{0}^{a} x!\,{\rm d}x\ ?.
$$

Or something like
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{3} x!\ {\rm d}x\ ?$.

Comment: What do you mean with $x!$? Do you mean $\Gamma(x+1)$ or $\lfloor x\rfloor!$?

Comment: I suppose it needs o be numerically computed.

Comment: What does numerically mean?

Comment: Numerical integration. I don't suppose that there is any closed form for the integral.

Comment: For positive $n\in$ **N** we have $~\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}x!~dx}{\displaystyle\int_{n-1}^nx!~dx}~ ~{\large\approx}~~n$.

Comment: @Lucian. I am very interested by your comment. Could you tell me how you arrived there ? I personally found a big similarity between $\int_{0}^{a} \Gamma (1+x)~dx}$ and $\Gamma(1+a)$. Do these two things overlap ? Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: There's not much to say, except for the fact that I have been “studying” these things for several years now, due to a combination of two accidental discoveries, made sometime in late $2012$ or [early](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_March_7#March_7) $2013$. One of them is described in detail in my *community wiki* answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639648). The other one can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_June_10#Basic_Demonstration_Required).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: How will you interpolate this function?

Comment: Probably the safer would be to generate tables and interpolate using cubic splines or any other method. Please notice that this is a visual observation and ... that I am almost blind !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very amazing problem. As I said earlier, I did not find any closed form for the integral and then I only performed numerical integrations.

What is surprizing if that $y(a)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a} \Gamma(1+x)~ dx$ looks very much to $x(a)=\Gamma(1+a)$ (plot the two curves as a function of $a$).

Taking into account Lucian's comment, I performed a parametric plot  and I observed that, for values of $a \gt 1$, $y$ is almost linear with $x$.

A regression $\log(y)=a +b \log(x)$, for the range $2 \leq a \leq 12$, leads to $a=-0.0775761$ and $b=0.949784$ with $R^2=0.999467$.

Comment: This makes me curious if we can at least find a value for the definite integral from $0$ to $1$, which would give us an explicit equation for your linear approximation.

Comment: @DavidH. It works for large values of $a$. This is very similar to Lucian's comment.

Answer (score 3):

The factorial function is only defined on the positive integers, so those don't make sense.  However, there is a generalization of the factorial called the Gamma function which you might want to check out.

Answer (score 3):

Using:

> [Taylor Series of Gamma Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618488/taylor-series-of-gamma-function/4395895#4395895):

$$\int_0^x t! dt=  \lim_{c\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m+1}c^{n+1}\int_0^x t^n dt\text E_{-n}(-c(m+1))}{m!n!} $$

to get the following after an index shift:

$$\int_0^x t!dt= \lim_{c\to\infty} \sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^mc^nx^n\text E_{1-n}(-cm))}{\Gamma(m)n!}=\lim_{c\to\infty}\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m+n}Q(n,-cm)}{\Gamma(m)n} \left(\frac xm\right)^n$$

[Shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5Bx%21%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Ceulergamma%7D%5D%2Csum%5Bsum%5B+%28%28-1%29%5E%28m%2Bn%29+%28eulergamma%2Fm%29%5En+Q%28n%2C+-2.9+m%29%29%2F%28n+gamma%28m%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5Bx%21%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Ceulergamma%7D%5D%2Csum%5Bsum%5B+eulergamma%5E%28n%29%2F%28n%29%21+2.9%5E%28n%29+%28-1%29%5E%28m%29%2Fgamma%28m%29+En%28-%28n-1%29%2C-2.9+%28m%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2C100%7D%5D) with [generalized exponential integral $E_v(z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=En%28v%2Cz%29) and [gamma regularized $Q(a,z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma+regularized). Hopefully there is a simplification.

Alternatively, we use the [exponential integral Ei$(z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Ei%28z%29)

$$\int x! dx=\int\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n t^{x+n+1}}{n!(n+x+1)}dx=\boxed{C+\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\text{Ei}((x+n)t)}{\Gamma(n)}}$$

[**Shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Nintegrate%5Bt%21%2C%7Bt%2C0%2Ceulergamma%7D%5D%2CN%5Bsum%5B%28%28-1%29%5E%28n-1%29+%28Ei%28%28n%2B+eulergamma%293%29-Ei%28n+3%29%29%29%2F%28Gamma%28n%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C300%7D%5D%2C10%5D). When truncating the sum, $n$’s upper bound must be much greater than $t$ to converge.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the limit?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, you want to compute

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{a} \Gamma(1+x)~ dx=\int_{0}^{a}x\Gamma(x)~ dx$$

Taking into account that

$$\Gamma(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}y^{x-1}\ e^{-y}~ dy$$

we have

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ e^{-y}\left (\int_{0}^{a}x y^{x-1}~ dx\right )~ dy$$

The inner integral is easy to calculate

$$\int_{0}^{a}x y^{x-1}~ dx=\frac{y^{a}(a\ln y-1)+1}{y\ln^2 y}$$

The end result

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{a}(a\ln y-1)+1}{y\ln^2 y}e^{-y}~ dy$$

In principle, we are done.

For a particular value of $a$ we can integrate numerically.

But does there exist any analytical expression for $I(a)$ is a separate question.

I'd bet money it doesn't exist.

But I'd be happy if I was wrong.