# Taylor Series of Gamma Function

Tags: calculus, soft-question, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

I have always wondered whether the Taylor Series of Gamma Function exists or not. I tried to find it, but in vain. I googled for it, but couldn't find it. Has anyone ever found its Taylor Series?

Comment: It certainly has Taylor series (say around $1$), but it does not have a Maclaurin series. See [How to obtain the Laurent Expansion of Gamma Function Around $z=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287555/how-to-obtain-the-laruent-expansion-of-gamma-function-around-z-0) for its Laurent series.

Comment: But Laurent series has negative exponents.

Comment: If $f(z)$ has a Laurent series with negative exponent terms around $z=a$, it cannot have a Taylor series around $z=a$.

Comment: Really!!? Ok, thank you soo much. What about its Taylor Series around 1? What are the coefficients?

Comment: Not a simple job either, see section 6.1 of https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/link/gammaFunction.pdf.

Comment: Are you looking for a truncated series expansion ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want the Taylor series, you basically need the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\Gamma(x)$. These express in terms of the polygamma function. Considering

$$d_n=\frac{\left[\Gamma(x)\right]^{(n)}}{\Gamma(x)}$$ the first terms are
$$d_1=\psi ^{(0)}(x)$$
$$d_2=\psi ^{(0)}(x)^2+\psi ^{(1)}(x)$$
$$d_3=\psi ^{(0)}(x)^3+3 \psi ^{(1)}(x) \psi ^{(0)}(x)+\psi ^{(2)}(x)$$
$$d_4=\psi ^{(0)}(x)^4+6 \psi ^{(1)}(x) \psi ^{(0)}(x)^2+4 \psi ^{(2)}(x) \psi
   ^{(0)}(x)+3 \psi ^{(1)}(x)^2+\psi ^{(3)}(x)$$ which "simplify" (a little !) when you perform the expansion around $x=a$, $a$ being a positive integer.

Comment: No, I am not looking for function evaluations as coefficients, but for the 'raw' numbers, like that in the Taylor Series of $sin(x)$.

Comment: You simply evaluate these functions at $x=a$

Answer (score 3):

See the [**Euler Mascheroni Integrals $\text I_n$**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniIntegrals.html):

$$(-1)^n\text I_n=\int_0^\infty e^{-z}\ln^n(z)dz=\Gamma^{(n)}(1)$$

Therefore:

$$\Gamma(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma^{(n)}(1)x^n}{n!}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\int_0^\infty e^{-z}\ln^n(z)dz\,x^n}{n!}  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\text I_n\ (-x)^n}{n!} $$

where $(n)$ is the $n$ derivative. From the linked article:

$$\Gamma^{(0)}(1)=\text I_0=1$$

$$\Gamma^{(1)}(1)=-\text I_1=-\text{eulergamma}=-\gamma$$
$$\Gamma^{(2)}(1)=\text I_2=\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}6$$
$$\Gamma^{(3)}(1)=-\text I_3=-\gamma^3-\frac{\gamma\pi^2}2-2\zeta(3)$$
$$…$$

where $\zeta$ is [the Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function),$\zeta(3)$ is [Apéry’s constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant), and $n\in\Bbb N$ for this problem. Please correct me and give feedback!

Here is an evaluation of the “incomplete $\text I_n$” integral with [**numerical proof for $n=3$,$u=4$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28integral+e%5E%28-t%29+ln%28t%29%5E4+from+0+to+3%29-%28-ln%283%29%5E%284%2B1%29+sum+%28-1%29%5Em%2Fm%21+expintegrale%28-4%2C-%28m%2B1%29+ln%283%29%29+from+m%3D0+to+20%29):

$$\int_0^u e^{-t} \ln(t)^n dt=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\int_0^u \ln(t)^n t^m dt=-\ln(u)^{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\text E_{-n}(-(m+1)\ln(u)$$

where appears the [Exponential Integral E](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpIntegralE.html) function. See [**@Weijun’s comment’s CSIE link**](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Eb89089/link/gammaFunction.pdf) for a general integral representation of $\Gamma^{(n)}(x)$. Therefore:

$$(-1)^{n+1}\text I_n=\lim_{u\to\infty}\ln(u)^{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\text E_{-n}(-(m+1)\ln(u)) $$

A series about $x=1$ is simplified as an $x!$ series. If  one estimates by truncating the series and estimating $t$, then the $n,m$ upper bounds must be much greater than $t$:

$$x! = \lim_{t\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m+1}t^{n+1}x^n\text E_{-n}(-t(m+1))}{m!n!}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eulergamma%21%2C-sum%5Bsum%5B+eulergamma%5En%2Fn%21+2.2%5E%28n%2B1%29+%28-1%29%5Em%2Fm%21+En%28-n%2C-2.2+%28m%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C80%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C80%7D%5D) with interchangeable sums. Similarly using the CSIE link, a series about $x=a$:

$$\boxed{\Gamma(x)=\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m+1}t^{n+1}\text E_{-n}(-t(m+a))(x-a)^n}{m!n!}}$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma%28eulergamma%29%2C+sum%5B+sum%5B%28eulergamma-1%2F2%29%5En%2Fn%21+%28%28-1%29%5E%281+%2B+m%29+ExpIntegralE%28-n%2C+-2.2+%281%2F2+%2B+m%29+%29+2.2%5E%28n%2B1%29%29%2F%28m%21%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C50%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C50%7D%5D).

Comment: Since you're evaluating the expansion of $\Gamma(x)$ around $x=1$, the polynomial part should be $(x-1)^n$, not $x^n$.

Comment: Or alternatively you could write that it's equal to $\Gamma(x+1)$, not $\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: @BorisDimitrov [Fixed series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma%28eulergamma%29%2C-sum%5Bsum%5B+%28eulergamma-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+2.2%5E%28n%2B1%29+%28-1%29%5Em%2Fm%21+En%28-n%2C-2.2+%28m%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C80%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C80%7D%5D). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7
has this:

$\dfrac1{\Gamma(z)}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_kz^k
$
where
$c_1=1,
c_2=\gamma$,
and
$(k-1)c_k
=\gamma c_{k-1}-\sum_{j=2}^{k-1}\zeta(j)c_{k-j}
$.

It also has

$\ln(\Gamma(1+z))
=-\ln(1+z)+z(1-\gamma)
+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k(\zeta(k)-1)\dfrac{z^k}{k}
$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\ge 1$ be an integer. Then the following holds true:

\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{\xi \rightarrow 0}\frac{d^n}{d \xi^n} \left( \Gamma[\xi] - \frac{1}{\xi} \right) = 
\frac{1}{n+1} \cdot
\sum\limits_{1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+\cdots+ (n+1) \cdot m_{n+1} = n+1}
\frac{(n+1)!}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} m_j!} \cdot
\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} \left( \frac{\psi^{(j-1)}(1)}{j!}\right)^{m_j}
\end{equation}

The Mathematica code below verifies the result for $n \le 10$.

```
In[3082]:= Clear[f]; xi =.; n = 9;
(*From definition*)
ex0 = Normal[Series[D[ Gamma[xi] - 1/xi, {xi, n}], {xi, 0, 0}]];


(*Using d'Hospital rule*)
ex = (D[ Exp[f[xi]], {xi, n}] + 
      xi/(n + 1) D[Exp[f[xi]], {xi, n + 1}]) /. 
    Exp[f[xi]] :> Gamma[xi] /. 
   Derivative[j_][f][xi] :> mPolyGamma[j - 1, xi];

ex = ex /. 
   mPolyGamma[m_, xi_] :> mPolyGamma[m, xi + 1] - (-1)^m m!/xi^(m + 1);

ex = Simplify[ex] /. xi Gamma[xi] :> Gamma[1 + xi] /. xi :> 0;

(*conjecture for generic n*)
ex1 = 1/(n + 1) Total[
    Flatten[DeleteCases[
      Flatten[Table[
        With[{mn = (n + 1 - Sum[eta m[eta], {eta, 1, n}])/(n + 1)}, 
         If[Element[mn, 
            Integers], {(n + 1)!/
             Product[ 
              m[xi]!, {xi, 1, 
               n + 1}] Product[(mPolyGamma[j - 1, 1]/j!)^m[j], {j, 1, 
               n + 1}]}, {}] /. m[n + 1] :> mn], 
        Evaluate[
         Sequence @@ 
          Table[{m[xi], 0, 
            Floor[(n + 1 - Sum[eta m[eta], {eta, 1, xi - 1}])/
             xi]}, {xi, 1, n}]]], n - 1], {}]]];
(ex - ex1) // Simplify

(ex0 - (ex /. mPolyGamma[j_, 1] :> PolyGamma[j, 1])) // Simplify

Out[3088]= 0

Out[3089]= 0
```