# Area under inverse gamma function branch from minimum to 1. Equivalent to $1-\int\limits_0^1x! dx=.077254…$ in closed form.

Tags: integration, inverse, factorial, gamma-function, inverse-function

I have an interesting question about an integral which follows from this question:

> [**Here.**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4135449/area-under-the-graph-of-a-number-multiplied-by-itself-a-negative-amount-of-times)

This is about the integral of the inverse gamma function, which is the solution of y to x=y!. This function will be denoted by [$y=Π^{-1}(x)$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_function) which is simply x! reflected around y=x. Here is the integral in question when we integrate over its domain. This constant will be denoted by Γ:

$$\mathrm{Γ=\int_{\mathrm{min}(x!),x>0}^1 Π^{-1}(x)dx=1-\int_0^1 x!dx⇔1-Γ=\int_I x! dx}$$

Here is the plot of the wanted figure. The minimum value in the lower bound is very close to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}=.886...\ $:[image: a]

> [$$\mathrm{Link!}$$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ictlmmzqwy)

Of course we can just do $$\mathrm{Γ=1-\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1x \sum_{n=0}^x\frac nx!=.077254...}$$ for the area of the black figure, which is obvious of how to derive it. Here is what the unmodified area looks like which obviously is unrealistic to integrate:
[image]

> [**Graph and sum**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kutzcnlyj4)

This will also give the area under the factorial/gamma function.

I will list out some other attempts soon enough. What is an alternate form of this boring Riemann Sum and Γ constant? This is simply based on the factorial function, the Desmos type and not the boring integer defined one, integrated over the unit interval denoted I. **You could try doing the unmodified area if you want**, but this probably is undefined or is infinite.As always, please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: [More reliable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857109/integral-of-factorial-function/4601417#4601417) series for this older informal post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible answer for the integral of the gamma function. This then can be used to find “Γ” constant:

From [source 1](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/06/01/01/01/) with the nth derivative and [source 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth+derivative+of+gamma%28x%29). Lets assume that the n=0 terms are by convention or limit defined. Here is a demo of the first series [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vfswhl0byo):

1.$$\mathrm{Γ(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{Γ^{(n)}(1)x^{n-1}}{n!},|x|<1}$$
2.$$\mathrm{Γ^{(n)}(x)=\lim_{t\to 0} t^{-n}\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^{n- m}\binom nm Γ(x+kt),n\in \Bbb N}$$

3.$$\mathrm {\int Γ(x)dx=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{\lim_{t\to 0} t^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom nk Γ(1+kt)}x^{n-1}}{n!}dx= \quad \lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \frac{{
(-1)^{n-k}Γ(1+kt)}x^n}{t^nnn!}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{Γ^{(n)}(1)x^n}{nn!},|x|<1}$$

Also, you can [use](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/06/01/04/01/) the fact that $$\mathrm{Γ(x+y)=Γ(y)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {Γ^{(n)}(y)x^n}{Γ(y)n!},y\not \in \Bbb Z\ and \ y\not \le 0}$$

Therefore:

$$\mathrm{\int Γ(x+y) dx=\int Γ(y)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {Γ^{(n)}(y)x^n}{Γ(y)n!} dx= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {Γ^{(n)}(y)x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}= \quad \lim_{t\to 0} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk\frac {(-1)^{n-k}Γ(y+kt)x^{n+1}}{t^n(n+1)!}, y\not \in \Bbb Z \ and \ y\not \le 0}$$

You can also use the classic Riemann Sum Definition:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k=a+kΔx)Δx, Δx=\frac {b-a}{n}$$
to find that:

$$\mathrm{\int_a^b Γ(x) dx=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n Γ\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)}$$

There also exists this [expansion](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/06/01/06/01/) for the reciprocal gamma function which can be used to find the [Fransén Robinson Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fransen-RobinsonConstant.html), aka F, as there does not appear to be a restriction on the series. I will take Wolfram’s Website’s word that it converges. $\mathrm x_0$ is any real value to produce a vertical shift.

$$\mathrm{F=\int_{\Bbb R^+}\frac {dx}{Γ(x)}= \frac1\pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{\pi^{k-n}(-1)^nΓ^{(n)}(1-x_0)}{n!(k-n)!} sin\left(\pi x_0+\frac{\pi(k-n)}{2}\right)\right)\frac{(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{k+1}  \mathop=^?\frac1\pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{\pi^{k-n}(-1)^n \lim_{t\to 0} t^{-n}\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^{n- m}\binom nm Γ(1-x_0+kt)}{n!(k-n)!} sin\left(\pi x_0+\frac{\pi(k-n)}{2}\right)\right)\frac{(x-x_0)^{k+1}}{k+1}}$$

Here is another [Beta Function](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta/21/01/01/) based answer with the [Pochhammer Symbol](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta/21/01/01/). Here is [proof](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/55waesmji5) this really works

$$\mathrm{\int\frac{Γ(x)}{Γ(x+y)}dx=\frac1{Γ(y)}\left(ln(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-y)_n}{n!}ln\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)\right)= \frac{lnx}{Γ(y)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{sin(\pi y)(n-y)!}{\pi n!}ln\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right),Re(y)>0}$$

Browsing Wolfram Mathworld made me find some generalized reciprocal factorial integral and generalized factorial integral functions. These are nicely named the [Lamda function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambdaFunction.html), [Mu functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MuFunction.html), and [Nu functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NuFunction.html). These may seem like they have the sole purpose of finding a closed form of an integral, but they should have some nice properties. Note I only list out a few:

$$\mathrm{λ(x,y)\mathop=^{def}\int_0^y \frac{t!}{x^t}dt, \frac{μ(x,y,z)\,y!}{x^z} \mathop=^{def}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^t t^y}{(t+z)!}dt,\frac{ν(x,z)}{x^z}=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^t}{(t+z)!}dt= \frac{μ(x,0,z)}{x^z},μ(x,y,0) \mathop=^{def}μ(x,y) ,ν(x,0) \mathop=^{def}ν(x)=μ(x,0,0)=μ(x,0)}$$

This means we can put our original problem and the [Fransén-Robinson constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Robinson_constant) in closed form. Note the conventions for Γ in the question:

$$\mathrm{Γ \mathop=^{def}\int_{min\ Γ(x), x>0}^1 Γ^{-1}(x)dx=1-\int_0^1 t! dt=1-λ(1,1)= 0.0772540493193693948561195176…}$$
$$\mathrm{F \mathop=^{def} \int_{\Bbb R^+} \frac{dx}{Γ(x)}=\int_0^\infty \frac{1^t t^0dt}{Γ(t-1+1)}=μ(1,0,-1) =ν(1,-1)= 2.8077702420285193652215011865577…}$$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: The Fransén-Robinson constant is also mentionned in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A058655)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks. How did you find this older post?

Comment: "How did I find this older post ?"1) By chance 2) Interesting.