# Is there an integral for $\int x! dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, factorial

I was curious and started reading up about non-elementary functions, and their integrals and asked myself how one would integrate the function $x!$, as I can't even imagine integrating the $\pi$ function but I am curious as to how someone else may do it because how would someone integrate the integral sign in the function. I'm not even sure where I would start with such a function.

Comment: If you want to consider $x!$ for non-integer $x$, you might want to use the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) suitably adjusted

Comment: I would not expect a closed form antiderivate. My guess is that we need numerical methods.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20Gamma(x)&dataset=

Comment: Sorry, but does this answer your question? [Integral of factorial function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857109/integral-of-factorial-function)